# Create variable number of dictionary with name taken from list in Python

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list which grows and shrinks in a for loop. The list looks like following :- . With every element inside list of list i want to associate it to a separate dictionary.

```
list123 = [[1010,0101],[0111,1000]]
```

In this case I want to create 4 dictionary with the following name

```
dict1010 = {}
dict0101 = {}
dict0111 = {}
dict1000 = {}
```

I tried following loop

```
for list1 in list123:
    for element in list1:
        dict + str(element) = dict()
```

This is the error i am getting

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you dynamically create variables in Python via a while loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-a-while-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while you can dynamically create variables, unless there is an overwhelming need to do that use instead a dictionary of dictionary witch key is the name you want, like this

```
my_dicts=dict()
for list1 in list123:
    for element in list1:
        my_dicts["dict" + str(element)] = dict()
```

and to access one of them do for example `my_dicts["dict1010"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can uses `globals()` function to add names to global namespace like this

```
for list1 in list123:
    for element in list1:
        globals()["dict"+str(element)] = {}
```

this will add variables with the names you want as if you created them using `dictx={}` also numbers that begins with 0 won't convert well using `str()` so you should make your list a list of strings

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I must say that you shouldn't do this. However, if you really want to, you can use `exec`.

If you really want to do this, you could use exec:

```
list123 = [[1010,0101],[0111,1000]]
for list1 in list123:
    for element in list1:
        var = 'dict' + str(element)
        exec(var + ' = dict()')
```